# How to search strings with certain number of occurence using Regular Expression?

Tags: python, regex

I am using regular expression to search for some string fit for my restrictions. For example, "`HHHHLLLHHHHHLLLLL`", I want to find the strings that letter `H`'s total occurence is more than 8.

I tried to construct a regular expression using `{8,}` to search for occurence of H equal or more than 8. However, it doesn't seem to work.

```
Str1 = '"HHHHLLLHHHHHLLLLL"'
m = re.search(r'regex', Str1).group(0)
```

Could anyone give me some suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to use regex.

```
Str1 = '"HHHHLLLHHHHHLLLLL"'
if Str1.count("H") >= 8 : print "match"
```

Comment: Good idea. I also wouldn't use a regex here, +1. But maybe there is a reason why she needs one?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Well I think regex is an overkill for this, I did however +1 you too for the regex solution. :)

Comment: Thanks. I just want to realize a plot in one paper and it says using regular regression matching. However, yours are awesome!

Answer (score 5):

```
re.search('(?:H[^H]*){8}', str1)
```

will find a match if there are at least 8 `H`s in your string.

But that's not really a good fit for a regex; FailedDev's solution will be *much* faster and is definitely easier to understand. So unless you have another good reason to use a regex, better go with his suggestion.

Comment: Still,  I am curious about how to write this kind of regex. Thank you for showing me that.